# Open Office Calc, Round up or down

Tags: openoffice-calc

I'm trying to output retail prices rounded to either a 4 or an 8 from various formulas

Is is possible to round one figure to the nearest of each of these?

Comment: Could you give an example with input values and desired output? E.g., given a retail price of 112 $, what's the expected result of the formula you're looking for?

Comment: Are you referring to whole dollar amounts, only?  You're looking for the last position to be a 4 or 8 rather than the price being a multiple of 4 or 8 ($32 is a multiple of 4 or 8 but doesn't end with 4 or 8)?  By "round", you mean up or down to the closest 4 or 8?  What would you want the result to be for a price of $11?

Comment: hi thanks for your replies. yes looking for the last position digit to be a 4 or 8 so for example 29 it would go up to 34 or 35 would go to 38

Answer (score 0):

Normally, a `ROUNDUP` or `CEILING` would go to the next multiple but you are asking to roundup to the next number with a 4 or 8 as last significant digit and the whole number may or may not actually be a multiple of 4 or 8. To do this, peel off the last digit and choose an appropriate *addend* to be used to adjust the original number.

[image: Round up to 4 or 8]

The formula in B1 is,

`=A1 + CHOOSE(INT(RIGHT(A1;1))+1; 4; 3; 2; 1; 0; 3; 2; 1; 0; 5)`

Fill down as necessary.